# Run-Time Error 91 When Trying to Find

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, runtime-error

I get Run-Time Error 91 when I run this. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
Sub deletingstuff2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long, wsh As Worksheet
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
i = 1
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row **<<ERROR IS HERE**

While i <= lngEndRowInv
If Cells(i, "C") = "Blue" Then
Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete
ElseIf Cells(i, "C") = "Diamond" Then
Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete
i = i - 1
lngEndRowInv = lngEndRowInv - 1
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you meant `wsh.Rows.Count`, not `Rows.Count`.

Comment: Found the error Changes the following:

Set wsh = ActiveSheet
Thanks!

Comment: Also instead of looping, have you considered Autofilter and then delete? It is much faster than looping :)